# What is it called when you override a method while calling a constructor?

Tags: java

Is there even a term for this? It has completely escaped me.

Example:

```
TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(context){
    @Override
    protected void onDetachedFromWindow(){
        super.onDetachedFromWindow();
        getRidOfDialog();
    }
};
```

Comment: I would say you define an inner class by doing that. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

That is an inner class defined on method's parameter. I think that the term you're looking for is "Anonymous inner class".

Answer (score 1):

It's an anonymous class. Consider the following just as an example.

```
new Thread(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println( "Message" ) ;
    }
} ) .start() ;
```

Can be represented as follows (same).

```
class ThreadDemo
{
    public void temp()
    {
        new Thread(new AnonymousClass()).start();
    }

    private class AnonymousClass implements Runnable
    {
        public void run()
        {
            System.out.println( "Message" ) ;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope you may have got some idea now. [See](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html).

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous inline class definition.